# coc-clangd has issues with gtkmm-4.0

Tags: c++, clang++, clangd

I have the hello world program from the `gtkmm` documentation. I can compile the program without any issues using:

```
g++ -o example main.cc example.cc `pkg-config "gtkmm-4.0" --cflags --libs`
```

**But the moment I go into neovim, coc-clangd has an error:**

```
In included file: no template named 'is_base_of_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_base_of'?
```

this happens at `#include "gtkmm/application.h"`

:CocInfo

```
vim version: NVIM v0.5.0
node version: v14.15.5
coc.nvim version: 0.0.80-37132cfc36
coc.nvim directory: /home/blah/.config/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: tmux
platform: linux
```

clangd is `12.0.0`

PS: I do have a compile_commands.json file, generated using `intercept-build` utility

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved it now, I encountered the same problem as you. I thought it was a problem with clangd, but I checked the [is_base_of_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and found that it only existed after C++17. If you use cmake to generate your project, just add:

```
set_property(TARGET ${target_name} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt to set the C++ standard to C++17.